# Unable to download the artifact maven-compiler-plugin from repository

Tags: maven-2

I've created a maven project and wanted to change the java compiler version to 1.6 so I added the ff:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>org.apache.maven.plugins</artifactId>
            <groupId>maven-compiler-plugin</groupId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run any maven goal in eclipse, it works. But when I run in terminal I got the ff errors:

```
Project ID: maven-compiler-plugin:org.apache.maven.plugins

Reason: POM 'maven-compiler-plugin:org.apache.maven.plugins' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  maven-compiler-plugin:org.apache.maven.plugins:pom:2.3.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  apache.repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases),
  jboss.repo.deprecated (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated),
```

Any idea what's causing this issue?

I was able to solved this issue by updating to maven3. But my problem right now is although I specified maven-compiler-plugin version to be 2.4, I'm still seeing 2.3.2 in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing maven 3 from a repository and added maven3 home in /etc/environment what I forgot to do is to reboot my machine, after that it worked.

My /etc/environment now looks like:

```
M3_HOME="/home/edward/java/apache/maven-3.0.4"
MAVEN_HOME="/home/edward/java/apache/maven-3.0.4"
M3="home/edward/java/apache/maven-3.0.4"

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/edward/java/apache/maven-3.0.4"
```

Here's how I uninstalled and install maven 3:
http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-maven-3-in-ubuntu-1110.html

Comment: You don't need to reboot a machine after installing Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Your groupId and artifactId are reversed.

Comment: The order doesn't matter I think.

Comment: It's not the order they're listed in that is the problem.  It's that you have the artifcatID list under the groupID and vice versa.  You need to switch the values.

Comment: see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1

Answer (score 2):

If Eclipse and the command line create different results, then they use different local Maven repositories. The default is in `$HOME/.m2/repository/`. So the first step is to find out which one (command line or Eclipse) uses a different local cache and why.

The next question is why the download failed. The usual reason is that Maven tried the download and got an error. Maven will remember the error and not try again. To force it to try again, you have to delete the folder `$M2_REPO/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/`.

Lastly, when you configure 2.4 but see 2.3.2 in the log, then you're either building the wrong project of one of the POMs of your build overwrites the version for the compiler plugin.

To avoid issues like this, use a parent POM where you keep all the versions in `dependencyManagement` (for dependencies) and `pluginManagement` (for plugins) elements. That way, you will never have to define a version in a module POM or in other projects which inherit from this one.