# ERROR: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, pom.xml

I am getting the below exception in my pom.xml when trying to run my application. I saw some posts regarding the error and followed them but no use. I understand the artifact(parent) is referred locally and is not present, but I don't know how to resolve this, could somebody please help me?

The error is

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure 
 to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
 from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-
 parent:pom:1.5.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/
 snapshot): repo.spring.io and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml is fine, it looks like it's a problem with your internet connection. Check if you can reach https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/ with your browser. If yes, check if you need to configure a proxy server. If no, you should contact your internet provider.

Here is the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) on how you configure a proxy server for Maven:

Comment: Did it help @user1245524

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the version of Spring Boot you are using, as it is a build. Just copy another release version of 1.X and replace it.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
    <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the url [https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/](https://repo.spring.io/snapshot//) from your browser, then it can be a Maven issue. Maven is unable to connect to the repository and that can be due to:

1. Any cache issues in the downloaded dependencies. Try deleting the local dependencies, and try out the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615071/2606228).
2. Try Maven Update and Maven Clean.
3. Try re-opening the IDE after doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Downgrade the spring boot starter to lower version.
2. Update the Maven project.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a firewall and/or using a VPN or in a corporate environment you will probably need to add one or more certificates to your Java Runtime cacerts file.

Go to https://repo.spring.io in the Chrome browser and then export the certificates by right clicking on the lock icon in the URL address bar, and then 'Connection is Secure,' then 'Connection is Valid' and the 'Details'. From there you can export one or more certificates.

Add these certificates to your Java Runtime cacerts using Java's keytool utility like this ( exact command will vary )

`keytool -trustcacerts -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias certificate-alias -import exported-CRT-file`